# How do I simplify this MGF?

Tags: sequences-and-series, moment-generating-functions

I've been trying to find the MGF for the following formula:

$$ {{r+x-1}\choose {x}} p^r(1-p)^x$$

with the following constraints $r>0$ and $0<p<1$ and finally x is discrete $x = 0,1,2,3...$

the MGF is:

$$ E(e^tx) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}e^{tx}{{r+x-1}\choose {x}} p^r(1-p)^x $$

and then I get the following:

$$ p^r\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}{{r+x-1}\choose {x}} ((1-p)e^t)^x$$

I'm kinda stuck here, how do I evaluate this sum? In specific, how do I evaluate the combination part, as $((1-p)e^t)^x = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^t}$  but the sum of the combination remains and I'm not too sure how to proceed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Use the identity $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k}nz^n=\frac1{(1-z)^{k+1}}$$ with $k=r-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$(-1)^x \binom{r+x-1}{x} = \binom{-r}{x}$